# Conflict installing phpMyAdmin while using latest version php version

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, centos

I am trying to install phpMyAdmin while already running `php5.6.8` from [webtatic](https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/) and it seems `php56w-common` is conflicting with phpMyAdmin's `php-common-5.4.16`

This is the error I am getting:

```
...
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

It seems the only way to deal with this problem, is to remove `php 5.6` and use `php 5.4` ... I would like to know if there are any other solutions.

Comment: Install phpMyAdmin manually rather than from a package.

Answer (score 0):

One Option is installing PhpMyAdmin manually and obviously that's a little bit complicated.so i suggest removing PHP 6 and installing xampp.
xampp is a free and open source cross-platform web server solution stack package, consisting mainly of the Apache HTTP Server, MySQL database, and interpreters for scripts written in the PHP and Perl programming languages.(it comes with phpmyadmin too)
[Here](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) is the link for downloading xampp.
The last version of xampp comes with PHP 5.6.8.so you wont need to use PHP 5.4.

Comment: Yeah, but unfortunately, I am not using postgres and nginx, not mysql, apache so that will be a problem for me.

Comment: so i'm afraid you should install phpmyadmin manually.here's how: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html